# Specified letter count with recursion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive algorithm that obtains to count specified a letter by user. But, I'm stuck in two cases. First, I think I must get `2` as result, I can't. Second, If there is no limit key, for instance the limit character specified as `z` by user , how the characters can be scanned up to end character here `g` ? The problem little bit complicated for me. I need your advices and ideas. Thank you all appreciated answers.

example string is: `how are you  i am testing`

another examples:

[image: example]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int lettercount(char* str, char key, char limit);

int main(){

    char test[]="how are you  i am testing";
    int num;

    num=lettercount(test,'a','t');

    printf("%d",num);

    return 0;
}
int lettercount(char* str, char key, char limit)
{
    int count = 0;

    if(str[0] == limit)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(str[0] == key)
    {
        lettercount(&str[1], key, limit);
        count++;
    }
    else
        lettercount(&str[1], key, limit);

        return count;
}
```

Comment: You need to check if str[0] is a NUL terminator `'\0'`, in addition to checking if it's equal to `limit`. Also, you return a `count` from the `lettercount` function, but you ignore the return value when calling the function recursively.

Comment: umm yes you are right about NULL. I returned count ? @user3386109

Comment: The last line of your function is `return count;`

Answer (score 0):

```
as the code is unwinding from the recursion(s)
it needs to accumulate the count
the following code should work for your needs.
Note: this returns 0 if key and limit are the same char

int lettercount(char* str, char key, char limit)
{
    int count = 0;

    if(str[0] == limit)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // implied else, more char in string to check

    if(str[0] == key)
    {
        count++;
    }

    count += lettercount(&str[1], key, limit);

    return count;
} // end function: lettercount
```

Answer (score 0):

With a recursive function, you need **3** things. **(1)** **set up** in the function that prepares for the next call; **(2)** **a recursive call**; and **(3)** **a way to terminate** the recursion. Here is one approach. **Note:** the version in the code below is a **long** version for readability, a **short** version is included at the end:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* recursively find the number of occurrences
of 'c' in 's' (n is provided as '0')
*/
int countchar (char *s, char c, int n)
{
    char *p = s;
    if (!*p)
        return n;

    if (*p == c)
        n = countchar (p+1, c, n+1);
    else
        n = countchar (p+1, c, n);

    return n;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "\n error: insufficient input. Usage:  %s <string> <char>\n\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int count = countchar (argv[1], *argv[2], 0);

    printf ("\n There are '%d' '%c's in: %s\n\n", count, *argv[2], argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/rec_c_in_s "strings of s'es for summing"  s

 There are '5' 's's in: strings of s'es for summing
```

You can make the function shorter, but slightly less readable with:

```
int countchar (char *s, char c, int n)
{
    char *p = s;
    if (!*p) return n;

    return countchar (p+1, c, (*p == c) ? n+1 : n);
}
```